# Massively under resourced cluster

Tags: memory, cluster-computing

I have a data set of X TB but a cluster with only 0.1X TB RAM,  is the best strategy to chop up the data 
and run 10 smaller jobs that will complete faster ( as I will be able to get most of the data into RAM , as it seems the jobs is stands is taking interminably long as I am guessing it is spending more time reading  / writing and spilling to disk

any suggestions , recommendations  welcome.

Comment: What kind of algorithm do you apply on your data ? Some of them (Neural Networks for instance...) are literally designed to work in parallel. Some others (K-Means clustering) would be much harder to be run in parallel. As it stands, your question is hard to answer because it lack specificity.

Comment: There is no algorithm per say , just reading a bunch of parquet files in SPark  and persisting to elastic search .  putting out feelers for best practices .....